# Sum of one open and one closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is open or closed or none? NBHM 2012 PhD question.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, contest-math

A and B are subsets of $R^n$ where A is open and B is closed. Define A+B as $$A+B= \{a+b: a\in A, b\in B \}.$$
is A+B open or closed or none of them?

I tried to consider n=1 and work with $\mathbb{R}$ only. By taking various examples I feel that A+B should be open. However, I am unable to come with a conclusion. Any help/hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: Write  $A+B=\cup_{b\in B} A+b $. Can you show  $A+b $ is open?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum of open/closed/compact sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ open/closed/compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1278251/sum-of-open-closed-compact-sets-in-mathbbrn-open-closed-compact)

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier yes that helped. Thanks!

Comment: The proposed duplicate does not directly address the issue of a sum of one open set and one closed set.  Thus I don't feel this target is really an "exact duplicate" although some ideas there are applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set is open but not necessarily closed:

1) $A+B$ open.
For every $b\in B$ the translate $A+b$  of $A$ is open (the translation by $b$ is an homeomorphism!)  and then $A+B=\bigcup_{b\in B}(A+b)$ that is an union of open subsets and is open.

2)  $A+B$ is not closed.
Consider $A=(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $b$ a point.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was thinking only to the worst case...